# How is Linux dealing with blocking I/O processes

Tags: linux, io, load, cpu

I have a system that does a lot of blocking network calls. Based on that the CPU idle time is relatively high as well as the overall system load. When I add more CPUs to the system idle time remains the same but system load drops. Why is that happening?

Is the following what is happening behind the scenes?

When a process that wants to do blocking network I/O is dispatched, the CPU prepares and propagates the call to the I/O bus, sets up the interrupt handler and then switches to another process as there is nothing else to be done. When the I/O call returns the I/O subsystem raises an interrupt and the CPU gets back to the original process in order to complete its execution.

Therefore, the job of the CPU consists here of interfacing with the I/O subsystem and of context switching. When there are many processes that need to go through this the load increases as a result of processes that wait for their I/O and their context switch. When I add more CPUs to the system there are less context switches per CPU and therefore less waiting and less load.

Is this a correct explanation? If yes, in which state are the processes the wait for their network I/O to finish? This should be runnable in order to affect the system load.

Answer (score 0):

All is well.  The load average is the number of processes waiting for CPU time; the more CPUs, the more the processes are spread across CPUs, so the shorter the length of the queue.  This works just like how the number of cashiers affect the line of customers wanting to check-out.